# Adaptive Card not working in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card where I take dates from the user using a date picker adaptive card. I have running code for my web client, which works perfectly, Now when I integrate my code using Azure Channels for Microsoft Teams, the bot works fine, I get to see the adaptive card also but when I press submit button after filling in the dates on the adaptive card I am getting this error

```
[11:39 AM] mts-bot
    Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot.ProcessLeaveApplicationLUIS(ITurnContext1 turnContext, LuisResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\nikhil\Alfi\mts-qna+luis\Bots\DispatchBot.cs:line 897
```

I have tried looking for a solution for this issue I followed what was said in this -
[Chat BoT Exception: OnTurnAsync exception-- Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652242/chat-bot-exception-onturnasync-exception-operation-returned-an-invalid-status?rq=1)

Here someone told to do this

```
var reply = new Activity();
```

to

```
var reply = turnContext.Activity.AsMessageActivity();
```

in onMessageActivityAsync method, but I am not sending a reply like this I am sending my response

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi how are you?"), cancellationToken);
```

Really looking ahead for a quick solution, I have raised the support request in Microsoft for this with ticket number 17896525 but its been 2 days not getting a solution from there.

```
 private Attachment LeavesDatesAdaptiveCardAttachment()
        {
            // combine path for cross platform support
            string[] paths = { ".", "Cards", "Dates.json" };
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
            var adaptiveCard = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);



            return new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),

            };
        }
```

Comment: Is this date-picker-card in a messaging extension or just conversation?

Comment: just conversation

Comment: Can you please share the adaptive card json

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NikhilBansal21/bb23e7ca4a3bd6114b536fe5751d6010

Comment: The shared JSON is working form me. I am able to submit from the adaptive card. 
Can you thy this [Adaptive card sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards/Bots/AdaptiveCardsBot.cs)

Comment: hi , i am calling the adaptive card in the same mentioned in the link

Comment: The above sample code should work. Are you still facing the error? If yes, then can you please share some more details about it? Where are you getting "BadRequest" error. is it in browser console or c# code?

Comment: yes i am still facing this issue. i am getting this issue specifically on Teams , i have same bot running fine on web widget

Comment: Can you please share some more code snippet on how you are rendering the card json ?
Are you adding ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive" in the attachment.

Comment: i have updated the code for rendering, pls check

Comment: @NikhilBansal, The only difference I could find with your code is the manifest schema. Can you try [Parse an AdaptiveCard from JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/authoring-cards/net#example-parse-an-adaptivecard-from-json)

Answer (score 0):

For rendering adaptive card in Teams we need to update data section for buttons in json file.

viz for web chat

```
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "data": "Your Button Data",
            "title": "feedback"
          }
```

For MS Teams:

````
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "data": {
              "msteams": {
                "type": "imback",
                "value": "Poor"
              }
            },
            "title": "feedback"
          }```
````